# Pandas - operations on groups using transform

Tags: python, pandas, transform

Here is my example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one'] ,
                   'B': ['Ar', 'Br', 'Cr', 'Ar','Ar'] ,
                   'C': ['12/15/2011', '11/11/2001', '08/30/2015', '07/3/1999','03/03/2000' ],
                      'D':[1,7,3,4,5]})

df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'])

def date_test(x):
    key_date = pd.Timestamp(np.datetime64('2015-08-13'))
    end_date = pd.Timestamp(np.datetime64('2016-10-10'))
    result = False

    for i in x.index:
        if key_date < x[i] < end_date:
            result = True

    return result

def int_test(x):
    result = False
    for i in x.index:
        if 1 < x[i] < 9:
            result = True

    return result
```

Now I am grouping by column `B` and transforming column `C` and `D`

The following code producess column of ones.

```
df.groupby(['B'])['D'].transform(int_test)
```

And the following code produces column of dates

```
df.groupby(['B'])['C'].transform(date_test)
```

I would expect them both to produce collection of ones and zeros and not dates. My goal is to get collection of ones and zeros. Any thoughts?

**Update**: My main goal is to understand how `transform` works.

Comment: explain the algorithm intent of int_test and date_test

Comment: @Boud, I am trying to generate mask from these two methods. With `date_test` I have different goals, but one particular goal is to found if group of dates has two consecutive days lying in particular time interval. This is my big goal, but I simplified it in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For type consistency with subsequent operations your can do with the results of a `transform` call, that function tries to cast the resulting Series into the dtype of the selected data it works against. The function source code has this dtype cast explicitly done.

Your boolean data can be turned into dates, thus you obtain a datetime series. Explicitly cast to `int` to get the expected type:

```
df.groupby(['B'])['C'].transform(date_test).astype('int64')
```

Comment: I tried it, but got back `TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]`

Comment: Hey, quick question, if `transform` fails to cast to original datatype, what happens then?

Comment: the function will except